# How can I complete directory entries that are under a subdirectory?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have an function in my `.zshrc` called `c` that is defined like so

```
c() {
cd ~/Code/$1
}
```

How can I teach ZSH to treat this `c` function just like I had done `cd ~/Code` from the command line so that it completes the projects underneath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer through another search just now. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14291189/177273) on Stack Overflow, I added the following to my `.zshrc`

```
compctl -/ -W ~/Code c
```

#### What do the options do?

- `-/` tells `compctl` to just complete file system paths
- `-W` tells `compctl` to implicitly add the value `~/Code` to the front of the completion.
- `c` is the thing to complete